# Arm assembly caesar cipher encryption

Tags: assembly, arm, caesar-cipher, rot13

I'm very new to arm assembly and I'm using armsim for a school project. I have multiple problems.

1. I need to read multiple lines from a txtfile and each line has a string that will take up to 85 bytes(per line). My program only reads the first line, I don't know how to read the rest of the file.
2. I have to take each character from each line and add 13 if the character value i'll call "a" ((a>=65 && a<=77) || (a>=97 && a<=109)). I have to subtract 13 if ((a>=78 && a<=109)||(a>=110 && a<=122)). If (a==32) then I print out the space and move onto the next character.I don't understand how to do this using branches...

The loop processes character by character and prints the character out into stdout.
Here is my code so far... I've spent days & hours on this and I just can't wrap my head around this. I have only been exposed to java up till now.

```
.equ SWI_Open, 0x66 @open a file
.equ SWI_Close,0x68 @close a file
.equ SWI_PrChr,0x00 @ Write an ASCII char to Stdout
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69 @ Write a null-ending string
.equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b @ Write an Integer
.equ SWI_RdInt,0x6c @ Read an Integer from a file
.equ SWI_RdStr, 0x6a @ Read string from file
.equ Stdout, 1 @ Set output target to be Stdout
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11 @ Stop execution
.global _start
.text
_start:

ldr r0,=InFileName @ set Name for input file
mov r1,#0 @ mode is input
swi SWI_Open @ open file for input
ldr r1,=InFileHandle
str r0,[r1]
ldr r7,[r1]
ldr r1,=array
mov r2,#85
swi SWI_RdStr @stores the string into =array 

mov r5,#0 @r5 is index

loop: @processes a single char then loops back
cmp r5,r2 @r2 is 83
bge procstop
ldrb r4,[r1,r5] @loads the character value from =array[r5] into r4

cmp r4,#77
ble add
cmp r4,#65
bge add

cmp r4,#97
bge add
cmp r4,#109 
ble add

cmp r4,#78
bge sub
cmp r4,#90
ble sub

cmp r4,#110
bge sub
cmp r4,#122
ble sub

add:
add r4,r4,#13

sub:
sub r4,r4,#13

mov r0,r4
swi SWI_PrChr

strb r4,[r1,r5]
add r5,r5,#1
B loop
procstop:

mov r0,#Stdout
swi SWI_PrStr
swi SWI_Exit

.data
InFileName: .asciz "lab4.txt"
EndOfFileMsg: .asciz "End of file reached\n"
ColonSpace: .asciz": "
NL: .asciz "\n " @ new line
array: .skip 85
.align
InFileHandle: .word 0


.end
```

Comment: Do you know C ? If you are not familiar with assembly, try to make the program in C, then translate it to assembly step by step, in place, until there is no C left.

Comment: I sadly do not know C.

Comment: What about another language ? C is better because it is closer to assembly, but other languages could work. The goal is to start with a program flow you are familiar with.

Comment: I have the program's pseudo code written in java. It should read each line until readLine returns null (end of file) but I'm not sure how to translate that into assembly. I'm thinking that the first part of the code is correct, and after processing all the characters in the first line of the file I would loop back to the beginning. Although I'm not sure how assembly iterates through file lines. In java it would just be bufferedreader.readLine()!=null, buffered reader would terminate each line by \n

Comment: With java, forbid `for` loops (only `while` and `do`/`while`). Use `char[]` instead of `String` and assume `readLine` works like `SWI_RdStr` and returns a `char[]`. To translate the `if`/`else if`, put a label before and after both `{}` blocks, and work out what jumps need to be done do have the same behavior.

Comment: Okay I got the file to read through every line. Didn't realize that it would read the end of the line and iterate on its own.

Comment: I don't know exactly how `SWI_RdStr` works, but it seems it will returns the number of characters read in r0, so you know there is no more to read when r0 is 0. Something like `while( SWI_RdStr(file,my_array,85) != 0)` in java.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I figured it out. I didn't know why I didn't think of this sooner. Don't need to compare all of those, just needed to do each comparison one at a time from the smallest comparison to the largest, basically a chain of if/else if statements